# GitLab and Puppet error

Tags: mysql, postgresql, centos, puppet, gitlab

I am attempting to install GitLab via Puppet, however I am receiving the following error, as per my manifest I am wishing to use MySQL, not PostgreSQL, can anybody point me in the right direction to fix this error?

**Error:**

```
Error: bundle install --without development aws test postgres --deployment returned 7 instead of one of [0]
Error: /Stage[main]/Gitlab::Install/Exec[install gitlab]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: bundle install --without development aws test postgres --deployment returned 7 instead of one of [0]
```

**Manifest:**

```
node gl {
  include epel
  include nexus

  package { 'createrepo' :
   ensure => 'installed',
  }

  Exec { path => [ "/bin/", "/sbin/" , "/usr/bin/", "/usr/sbin/" ] }
  class { '::mysql::server':
    root_password  =>  'root',
    databases => { 'gitlab' => { 'ensure' => 'present' } }
  } ->
  class { 'gitlab':
    git_email      => 'git@git.com',
    git_comment    => 'Gitlab',
    gitlab_domain     => 'gl',
    gitlab_dbtype     => 'mysql',
    gitlab_dbname     => gitlab,
    gitlab_dbuser     => root,
    gitlab_dbpwd      => root,
    ldap_enabled      => false,
  }
}
```

Comment: The `--without ... postgres` means that postgres will indeed not be installed. You should run this command from a shell to see what's causing it to fail (a common candidate is a missing ruby-dev package or similar).

Comment: Exit status 7 in context of a bundle install means that a bundle can't be found. Use command line to find out which one.

Comment: If puppet installs ruby from source, I think you should also add `/usr/local/bin/` to the path array.